# Can we load junit test method in /test package on submit action from GUI in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, webdriver

What I am trying to do is, I want to execute a specific Junit test (`/src/test/java/`) after each submits action(`src/main/java/`) from the web portal in spring boot.

Can we achieve unit test execution runtime on the basis of web action?
I am able to execute the Junit test successfully in one go once I click on `run as -> Junit test` , but I want it to get executed on submit action.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are trying to do, you want to have a running web application which you can access using your browser, BUT you want to trigger some unit test when you trigger some action (like submitting a form). Is this right?

Comment: Yes. I want to trigger Unit test in src/test/java package which spring provides for testing purpose.